# tc - неожиданное поведение

Tags: linux, сеть, tc

Изучаю `tc`, возникло неожиданное поведение при вводе команд

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
```

```
# tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: prio 10 protocol ip u32 \
    match ip protocol 6 0xff match ip dport 53 0xffff \
    police rate 3mbit burst 10k drop
```

Проблема состоит в том, что команды отрабатывают без вывода ошибки, но сам фильтр затем не отображается (команда `# tc filter show`)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Из-за eht0 вместо eth0?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, нет, просто опечатка